# MySQL SUM top n values for several columns and group

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a MySQL table containing player points for serveral categories (p1, p2 etc) and player id (pid).

I have a query that counts SUM of points for each category, puts them as aliases and groups them by player id (pid).

```
   SELECT *, 
   SUM(p1) as p1, 
   SUM(p2) as p2, 
   SUM(p3) as p3, 
   SUM(p4) as p4, 
   SUM(p6) as p6, 
   SUM(p13) as p13, 
   SUM(p14) as p14, 
   SUM(p15) as p15, 
   SUM(p16) as p16, 
   SUM(p17) as p17, 
   SUM(p18) as p18, 
   SUM(p19) as p19, 
   SUM(p20) as p20, 
   SUM(p21) as p21 
FROM results GROUP BY pid
```

Futher I do a while loop and update other table with these alias values.

Now I have a need to count only top 5 or 12 (depending on a category) values for each group. I don't know where to start. I found similar questions, but none of them addresses putting value in an alias, so i don't have to change futher code.

Can someone help me, and write an example query for at least two categories, so i can understand a principle of doing this right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Normalise your data.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to work with existing database structure

Comment: Luckily, we don't! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As we need to do sum of top n records, we need to use something like this:

```
SELECT pid, sum(p1)
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             (@pn := if(@p = pid, @pn + 1,
                        if(@p := pid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM player p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @p := 0, @pn := 0) as p1
      ORDER BY pid, p1 DESC
     ) p
WHERE seqnum <= 1
GROUP BY pid;
```

Here, we can modify `seqnum <= 1` condition as per the number of records needed. E.g. if we want 5 records then we need to write `seqnum <= 5`.

Please note that this will only calculate Top n sum for a particular field. If we want multiple fields then we may need to repeat the query.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/217ea1/32/0) is the SQL Fiddle example to play around with.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like it works great! But as I said, I want multiple fields (p1, p2 etc). Is it possible to do in one query? If yes, can you provide example with 2 fields?

Comment: With the current design, unfortunately it's difficult to query for multiple columns. However, we can write a stored procedure (or something) which uses this query and supply the column name as an argument to get the values.

Comment: It's difficult, but is it possible? OR i will have to use multiple queries?

Comment: Can you please have a look at @Kickstart's answer? That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @DarshanMehta , you can do repeated sub queries like that. Note that the variable names in each sub query need to be different.

Something like this, assuming you have a table of players:-

```
SELECT players.pid,
        suba1.p1sum,
        suba2.p2sum
FROM players
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT pid, SUM(p1) AS p1sum
    FROM (SELECT r.pid,
                r.p1,
                @p1n := if(@p1 = pid, @p1n + 1, 1) AS seqnum,
                @p1 := pid
          FROM results r 
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p1 := 0, @p1n := 0) as p1
          ORDER BY r.pid, r.p1 DESC
         ) sub1
    WHERE seqnum <= 5
    GROUP BY pid
) suba1
ON players.pid = suba1.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT pid, SUM(p2) AS p1sum
    FROM (SELECT r.pid,
                r.p2,
                @p2n := if(@p2 = pid, @p2n + 1, 1) AS seqnum,
                @p2 := pid
          FROM results r 
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p2 := 0, @p2n := 0) as p2
          ORDER BY r.pid, r.p2 DESC
         ) sub1
    WHERE seqnum <= 5
    GROUP BY pid
) suba2
ON players.pid = suba1.pid
```

Comment: Thank you! In your example you have 2 tables - players and results, but I have only 1 table - results.

Comment: It was an assumption I made that you had a table of players as well (after all, you do seem to have a field of pid which I assumed was player id). However if needs be you can use a sub query to get a list of the unique pids from the results table.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a table with all that SUM information, and use this one:

```
SELECT * from newTable ORDER BY p1 DESC LIMIT 5;
```

and you can catch all info that you want, by changing the field **p1** and **LIMIT 5**

Comment: You obviously did not understand my question